# Google sheets script copy data sets from one sheet to another (values only) at the top of the sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a task that requires that I move data from one sheet to another (much like a log). I prefer that the each time more data is added it be to the top of the log sheet. Lets say sheet "index generation" has data in the first 3 rows. The three rows from "index generation" needs to be added to the top of sheet "index" without over-righting or having more than just 3 rows added.

Thanks for any help you might be able to offer!

Here is the current status but it has cannot find function getActiveSpreadSheet in object SpreadsheetApp.

```
function IndexCopy() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadSheet();
  var indexGen = ss.getSheetByName('Index Generation')
  var index = ss.getSheetByName('Index');
  var Rows = indexGen.range.getValues();
  var array = sheet.range.getValues();
array.splice(0, 0, Rows);
  // add three rows to sheet.range then 
index.range.setValues(array)
};
```

Comment: does my answer helped you?

Comment: Go  to sheet [documenation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) there's several ways to insert rows. And in the range [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) there's several way to read and write data. It's good to get use to referring  to the documentation when you write code because it's constantly changing and changes often make it into the documentation before they make  it into  'content assist'.

Comment: at this point your code won't work, too many mistakes and the range hasn't been defined. as @Cooper said there's many ways to insert datas in your spreadsheet. BTW SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() should work.

Comment: Thanks for your method @cooper

Comment: @jsmith is working with me at the moment. Will post the final code that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'indexCopy')
      .addToUi();
}

function indexCopy()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src = ss.getSheetByName('source');
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName('destination');
  var srcDatas = src.getDataRange().getValues();
  var destDatas = dest.getDataRange().getValues();
  var i = srcDatas.length - 1
  while (i >= 0)
    destDatas.splice(1, 0, srcDatas[i--]);
  dest.getRange("A1:B" + destDatas.length).setValues(destDatas);
}
```

look at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: I didn't know about the array.splice! That is super useful. 

I am getting an error "spreadsheet" not defined. Thoughts?

Comment: this is only pseudo code. You'll have to set yourself the range and use SpreadsheetApp instead of spreadsheet. But again this only pseudo code so you'll have to find yourself the other things. Cheers

Comment: Thanks JSmith! I am trying to get it refined. See edits to my post.

Comment: can you send the link of your spreadsheet in comment you can delete it after

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OlAUtEqe9NRryHuwbEzMuBmhdZ8BCdMAkdMnUiZ24iA/edit#gid=1116848249

Comment: Obviously not the document I need it done, just a mock up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:
You first have to select the number of rows you want to move from the Index Generation Sheet and then run this function.

```
function IndexCopy() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var igSht=ss.getSheetByName('Index Generation');
  var igRg=igSht.getActiveRange();
  var igA=igRg.getValues();
  var iSht=ss.getSheetByName('Index');
  for(var i=0;i<igA.length;i++){
    iSht.insertRowBefore(1);
    iSht.getRange(1,1,1,igA[i].length).setValues([igA[i]]);
  }
  igSht.deleteRows(1, igA.length);
}
```